# Prevent overwriting of blocks with same name in Go html/template

Tags: html, go

I'm having difficulty in rendering the correct content using templates in Go.

I have a base template (`base.tmpl`) and 2 child templates (`a.tmpl` and `b.tmpl`).

```
// base.tmpl
{{ define "base" }}
  {{ template "header" . }}
  {{ template "content" . }}
  {{ template "footer" . }}
{{ end }}
```

```golang
// a.tmpl
{{ template "base" . }}
{{ define "content" }}
  This is a.tmpl
{{ end }}
```

```golang
// b.tmpl
{{ template "base" . }}
{{ define "content" }}
  This is b.tmpl
{{ end }}
```

When executing `a.tmpl` the contents of the content block in `b.tmpl` are inserted.

For example, rendering `a.tmpl` results in a page displaying:

```
This is b.tmpl
```

I am parsing the templates (see below) and returning and assigning the result to a variable `x` so I may call `x.ExecuteTemplate(w, "a.tmpl", nil)`

```golang
func parseTemplates() *template.Template {
    templ := template.New("")
    err := filepath.Walk("./templates", func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if strings.Contains(path, ".tmpl") {
            _, err = templ.ParseFiles(path)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
            }
        }

        return err
    })

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return templ
}
```

I am assuming this is because when parsing the templates, Go keeps `b.tmpl`'s content block definition as the most recent.

I'm wondering if there's a way where I can parse all templates at run time and simply call the template I want to execute without having to re-parse the header, content, footer etc. each time I execute the page.

Comment: Please include your code for parsing and rendering the templates so the issue can be reproduced... https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks @Gavin, I have added the parsing and rendering functions.

Answer (score 1):

Parse the templates for a and b separately.

```
atmpl, err := template.ParseFiles("base.tmpl", "a.tmpl")
if err != nil { /* handle error */ }

btmpl, err := template.ParseFiles("base.tmpl", "b.tmpl")
if err != nil { /* handle error */ }
```